# Send payment using Blockchain.info API - Runtime Error: ERROR: For input string: ".001"

Tags: python, json, api, blockchain

I am trying to send a payment using Blockchain.Info's payment API. I am using a Python libary found on GitHub here: https://github.com/gowness/pyblockchain/blob/master/pyblockchain.py

When running the code below I am getting the following error: RuntimeError: ERROR: For input string: ".001" Does anyone know what is going on here? I am running Python 2.7. Once I have got the initial sending of one transaction working I would like to look at sending multiple transactions.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import islice, imap
import csv, requests, json, math
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import urllib
import json
from os.path import expanduser
import configparser

class Wallet: 
guid        = 'g'
isAccount   = 0
isKey       = 0
password1   = 'x'
password2   = 'z'
url         = ''

def __init__(self, guid = 'g', password1 = 'x', password2 = 'z'):

    if guid.count('-') > 0:
        self.isAccount = 1
        if password1 == '': # wallet guid's contain - 
            raise ValueError('No password with guid.')
    else:
        self.isKey = 1

    self.guid = guid
    self.url = 'https://blockchain.info/merchant/' + guid + '/'

    self.password1 = password1
    self.password2 = password2

def Call(self, method, data = {}):
    if self.password1 != '':
        data['password'] = self.password1 
    if self.password2 != '':
        data['second_password'] = self.password2

    response = requests.post(self.url + method,params=data)

    json = response.json()
    if 'error' in json:
        raise RuntimeError('ERROR: ' + json['error'])

    return json

def SendPayment(self, toaddr='TA', amount='0.001', fromaddr = 'FA', shared = 0, fee = 0.0001, note = 'test'):
    data = {}
    data['address'] = toaddr
    data['amount'] = amount
    data['fee'] = fee


    if fromaddr != '':
        data['from'] = fromaddr

    if shared == 1:
        data['shared'] = 'true'

    if note != '':
        data['note'] = note

    response = self.Call('payment',data)

    return

def SendManyPayment(self, txs = {} , fromaddr = 'FA', shared = 0, fee = 0.0001, note = 'test'):
    responses = {}

    for tx in txs:
        SendPayment(self, tx[0], tx[1] , fromaddr , shared , fee , note )

    return 



 print(Wallet().SendPayment())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, payment amount needed to be in Satoshi not BTC. Should have looked at the API docs a bit more first ;)